# "Calculus 3rd Edition" by Michael Spivak -- Chapter 2 Problem 4 (a). Solving the problem (unclear answer book).

Tags: combinatorics, polynomials, summation, proof-explanation, combinations

Answer book is unclear to me on the following question. Would apreciate if someone could clear it up for me. Thanks in advance.

---

"Calculus 3rd Edition" by Michael Spivak -- Chapter 2 Problem 4 (a) states:

> Prove that
>   $$\sum_{k=0}^l{n\choose k}{m\choose l-k}={n+m\choose l}$$
>   Hint: Apply the binomial theorem to $(1+x)^n(1+x)^m$.

"Answer Book for Calculus" shows the following answer:

> Since
>   $$(1+x)^n(1+x)^m=(1+x)^{n+m}$$
>   we have
>   $$\sum_{k=0}^n {n\choose k}x^k\cdot\sum_{j=0}^m{m\choose j}x^j=\sum_{l=0}^{n+m}{n+m\choose l}x^l$$

(so far no problem) ***

> But the coefficient of $x^l$ on the left is clearly
>   $$\sum_{k=0}^l{n\choose k}{m\choose l-k},$$
>   one term of the sum ocurring for each pair $k,j=l-k$.

I can´t seem to understand what comes after "***" ¿How did he arrive at $\sum_{k=0}^l{n\choose k}{m\choose l-k}$? ¿How would this prove the initial statement?

Comment: you know that two polynomials are equal iff the coefficients of the monomials $x^k$ are?

Comment: I guess I do now.

Comment: well, that's what is being used here. The coefficient of $x^l$ on the right hand side is immediate, on the lhs you have to sort terms. Then compare.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $p,q$ are polynomials, then we have $p(x)=\sum_i p_i x^i$ and $q(x) = \sum_j q_j x^j$ where for
convenience I am assuming that $p_i, q_j$ are non zero for a finite number of terms.

If $p(x)=q(x)$ for all $x$ it is straightforward to show using evaluation & differentiation that $p_k=q_k$ for all $k$.

If $r(x) = p(x) q(x)$, then $r(x) = \sum_i \sum_j p_i q_j x^{i+j}$. Using the transformation $l=i+j, j=j$, we have
$r(x)= \sum_l ( \sum_j p_{l-j} q_j ) x^l$. That is, the $l$th coefficient of $r$ is
$ \sum_j p_{l-j} q_j $.

Now let $p(x)= (1+x)^m$, $q(x) = (1+x)^n$, $r(x) = (1+x)^{m+n}$.

The $l$th coefficient (I'm taking $l \in \{0,...,m+n\}$ here) of $r$ is $\binom{n+m}{l}$, and, using the formula above
we have $ \sum_j p_{l-j} q_j $ and we have
$ \sum_j p_{l-j} q_j  = \sum_{j=0}^l  \binom{n}{j} \binom{m}{l-j}$.

Note that $\binom{n}{j} = 0$ for $j >n$, and similarly for the other term.